# How to set storyboard on launch in iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, storyboard, splash-screen

On application load storyboard appears only for few seconds and after white screen appears till the app is loaded. How exclude white screen so user would see only storyboard till the app is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your launch storyboard for a bit, then it switches to a white screen, my guess is that you're doing too much in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. The launch storyboard will go away when either

1. Your main storyboard's initial view controller is loaded.
2. You assign something to the window's `rootViewController` property.

Check for work in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` that blocks the main thread, which will delay the display of your app's real UI.

Edit: I see your `react-native` tag, so the above is probably not directly applicable to you. I'm not a RN guru, but a quick check of the docs leads me to think that you need to dig into the initial component in your app and look for things in there that might hold up rendering. It's the same idea as my suggestion above, just in a different context.

Comment: Indeed, white screen appears when the js is loading.
This package helped me to prolong splash screen till js is loading:
react-native-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

It's not a white screen. It's splash screen for iOS application.

That white screen is `launchScreen`.

Check `LaunchScreen.storyboard` in your project.

You can customise it.

And you can not avoid it.

Comment: I already have LaunchScreen.storyboard in my project and it appears but only for 1-2 seconds then it changes to white screen. Can I set storyboard till app is fully loaded?